# how does awk differentiate string from number

Tags: awk

How is a file read by different filehandlers. I assume most of them read it as string. For e.g. in awk, if a file subsequently split according to the delimiter then how does it differentiate a numeric field from a string field (if CONVFMT is not specified) ?

Comment: It differentiates fields by how you use them. If you do a `+1` for example, it'll try to parse the field into a number.

Comment: See Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins which includes this section: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat it as string it will be an string, if you try to do a numeric op it will be parsed to a number and it will perform this op.